# Transactions spanning multiple schemas in a database

Tags: java, oracle

I have a single connection which does DML on objects in two different schemas of an Oracle database.  I complete a transaction involving objects in `schema A` and then start a second transaction to work with objects in `schema B`.  If any errors occur when I am working in the second transaction, I want to roll back the changes for both transactions.  Is that possible?

Comment: You've tagged this question Oracle.  Are you using the term "database" the way Oracle defines the term?  If so, it is not possible to have a single connection to multiple databases.  Or, using Oracle terminology, are you referring to a process that modifies data in two different schemas of the same database?

Comment: I am refering two different schemas of the same database

Comment: OK, I think I edited your question to clarify what you're saying-- please make sure that I have understood the question correctly.

Comment: yes correct what exactly I meant

Answer (score 2):

If you want the changes that are made to both schemas to be committed or rolled back together, you need to use a single transaction.  Once you commit the first transaction, you cannot then roll it back if the second transaction fails (well, potentially, you could using flashback technology but it gets **way** more involved).  If you used a single transaction for the work you are doing on both schemas, however, you'd get the behavior you desire that all the changes would be committed or rolled back atomically.

Comment: I understand it thanks for your information can u please give one simple example.Because as a newbie it is very useful for me..

Comment: @BALASCJP - An example of what, exactly?  Modifying data in two different tables (that happen to be in the same schema) in a single transaction?  Are you using straight JDBC?  JPA?  Or some other API to access the database?

Comment: -Modifying data in two different tables (that happen to be in the same schema) in a single transaction...I am using Straight JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Set your `Connection` so it doesn't autocommit (which it does by default), e.g.:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Then you can run the DML against the first schema and, using the same connection object, run your DML against the second schema. If something fails, roll everything back, e.g:

```
conn.rollback();
```

Otherwise, if everything succeeded, commit:

```
conn.commit();
```

Comment: GriffeyDog we can't access two schema with single connection but we can achieve it through single transaction ok correct if am wrong.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you are directly connecting to each of the two schemas with your JDBC database connections. I suggest setting up a separate schema that your application can use to connect to the Oracle database, and grant appropriate privileges TO this schema FROM the existing two schemas for whatever database objects you need to access, creating synonyms as appropriate/necessary. Then you will only need a single JDBC connection.